# How are dataset mapping operations evaluated, if not on the TensorFlow graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm inexperienced with TensorFlow. The tutorials I have seen explain that Python operations on `tf.Tensor`s build an abstract computational graph, parts of which are later evaluated. Thus, in the following code, I was expecting to see that `tf.cast` would be an operation on the default graph. It is not. If this operation isn't evaluated on the default graph, how is it evaluated?

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> def mapper(src):
...     print('in mapper')
...     return tf.cast(src, tf.float32)
...
>>> d = tf.data.Dataset.range(2).map(mapper)
in mapper
>>> get_next = d.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
...     print(sess.run(get_next))
...     print(sess.run(get_next))
...
0.0
1.0
>>> tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
[<tf.Operation 'start' type=Const>, <tf.Operation 'stop' type=Const>, <tf.Operation 'step' type=Const>, <tf.Operation 'OneShotIterator' type=OneShotIterator>, <tf.Operation 'IteratorToStringHandle' type=IteratorToStringHandle>, <tf.Operation 'IteratorGetNext' type=IteratorGetNext>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map function gets run as a TensorFlow graph function, i.e. is [wrapped in a `Defun` decorator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/07e497b0ad3f0e102e167a50de2b543a4a238fde/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1536). `Defun` is not yet part of the public TensorFlow API, but you can read about it in the [Defun class docstring](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/07e497b0ad3f0e102e167a50de2b543a4a238fde/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py#L44).

So on one level it's a new graph because that's how `Defun` is implemented. I believe `Dataset` uses a `Defun` here so that the mapping transformation can be applied on different devices/workers without blowing up the size of the graph (and so any variables used are lifted out and defined once).